# D3js forced directed graph animation and reload issue

Tags: d3.js, graph, force-layout

Below code generates a force directed graph but there are couple of problems.

1. Like how do I control the opening animation speed
2. How do I change the drag speed
3. And major problem every time I try to drag some element it reloads automatically.

I not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
var width = $(window).width(),
        height = 700;

var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .on("tick", tick2);




var svg = d3.select("body .banner").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
//.on("click", explicitlyPosition);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
        node = svg.selectAll(".node");

function tick2() {
    link
            .attr("x1", function (d) {
                return width * 0.5;
            })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return height * 0.5;
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return width * 0.5;
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return height * 0.5;
            });

    d3.selectAll("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return width * 0.5;
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return height * 0.5;
            });

    d3.selectAll("text")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return width * 0.5;
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return height * 0.5;
            });
    tick();
}
function tick() {
    link.transition()
            .attr("x1", function (d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });

    d3.selectAll("circle").transition()
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            });

    d3.selectAll("text").transition()
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            });
}

var graph = {
    "nodes": [
        {"name": "You", "val": "You", "x": width * 0.50, "y": height * 0.5, "fixed": false},
        {"name": "SaaS", "val": 768, "x": width * 0.40, "y": height * 0.14, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "Education", "val": 1021, "x": width * 0.65, "y": height * 0.10, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "E-Commerce", "val": 1345, "x": width * 0.75, "y": height * 0.35, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "Food Tech", "val": 512, "x": width * 0.70, "y": height * 0.72, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "Healthcare", "val": 246, "x": width * 0.57, "y": height * 0.70, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "Fashion Industry", "val": 657, "x": width * 0.30, "y": height * 0.80, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "Hardware", "val": 145, "x": width * 0.30, "y": height * 0.65, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "Fintech", "val": 1160, "x": width * 0.25, "y": height * 0.18, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "Series A", "val": 392, "x": width * 0.85, "y": height * 0.13, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "Series B", "val": 873, "x": width * 0.80, "y": height * 0.60, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "2014", "val": 592, "x": width * 0.125, "y": height * 0.25, "fixed": true},
        {"name": "2015", "val": 630, "x": width * 0.19, "y": height * 0.45, "fixed": true}
    ],
    "links": [
        {"source": 0, "target": 1},
        {"source": 0, "target": 2},
        {"source": 0, "target": 3},
        {"source": 3, "target": 9},
        {"source": 3, "target": 10},
        {"source": 0, "target": 4},
        {"source": 0, "target": 5},
        {"source": 0, "target": 6},
        {"source": 0, "target": 7},
        {"source": 0, "target": 8},
        {"source": 8, "target": 11},
        {"source": 8, "target": 12}
    ]
};




link = link.data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

node = node.data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", function (d) {
            you_val = (d.val === "You") ? 1500 : d.val;
            return ((you_val) / 30) < 15 ? 15 : ((you_val) / 30);
        });

node.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("fill", "#9a9a9a")
        .attr("font-size", "12px")
        .attr("font-weight", "600")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.val;
        });

node.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("dy", function (d) {
            you_val = (d.val === "You") ? 1500 : d.val;
            var rad = ((you_val) / 30) < 15 ? 15 : ((you_val) / 30);
            return (rad + 15) + "px";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("fill", "#9a9a9a")
        .attr("font-size", "12px")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        });

force
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .start();
```

Comment: What does your HTML file look like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have two tick functions.

1. How do I change the drag speed
2. And major problem every time I try to drag some element it reloads automatically.

Just have a single tick function like this:

```
function tick2() {
    link
            .attr("x1", function (d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });

    d3.selectAll("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            });

    d3.selectAll("text")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            });
}
```

In your case you have two tick functions, both have a very different logic.

3) Like how do I control the opening animation speed

You have specified the node as fixed with x and y

Like: `{"name": "You", "val": "You", "x": width * 0.50, "y": height * 0.5, "fixed": true}`

In this case the force layout does not calculate the x and y since you have said its a fixed node which means it cannot be moved via force layout.

In case you want the layout to have animation on load to calculate its own place read this awesome [tutorial](http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/)

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AWwrAiMTSWkuEgSKNU0p?p=preview)

Comment: I need scale up opening animation when the page loads as I have now but animation restarts as I drag some a node. using one tick function as you suggested the graph directly appears also i need the drag effect [link](http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/)